# jQuery find call issue

Tags: jquery, find

I'm having the following code:

```
Test = function(options){
  var value;
  for(option in options){
    value = options[option];
    this[option] = value;
  }

  this.sbOptions = this.el.find('.ulp-layer .sbOptions');
  this.hotelSelector = this.el.find('select[name="hotelname"]');
  this.hotelSelector.selectbox();

  console.log(this.sbOptions); // not finding the element
  console.log(this.el.find('.ulp-layer .sbOptions')); // finds the element
};

var testPage = new Test({
   el: $('.page')
});
```

I can't figure it out why those two console.log lines are not returning the same elements. Can you please give me a hint?
Thank you!

Comment: What does `this.sbOptions` contain ?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, take a look here, open the console https://jsfiddle.net/hoyyqm1d/

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] (maybe in jsfiddle) showing it not working?

Comment: @YoYo it's right there in the code

Comment: If the code provided is not your actual code, it could be to do with the use of `this` which will be different in (eg) callbacks.

Comment: And what does `.selectbox()` do in your edit?   Sounds like it would manipulate the DOM, which would change the elements.

Comment: I've updated the code above with 2 extra lines.
this.sbOptions didn't contain the element that I was expecting because that sbOptions element wasn't yet added to DOM. this.hotelSelector.selectbox() was doing this. I had to move this.sbOptions = this.el.find('.ulp-layer .sbOptions'); after this.hotelSelector.selectbox(); in order to work. Stupid mistake that I made.